# Why done() is not called until modal dialog closed?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, modal-dialog, swingworker

In an example below, an attempt made to open dialog on worker start and to close it on worker end.

Unfortunately, `done()` is not executed until dialog closed manually.

Why?

```
package tests.javax.swing;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Try_SwingWorker_Modality {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Try_SwingWorker_Modality.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {





                AbstractAction popupAction = new AbstractAction("popup") {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "popup");
                    }

                };

                final JDialog dialog = new JDialog((JFrame)null, true);
                dialog.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                dialog.add(new JButton(popupAction));


                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);



                SwingWorker<Object,Object> swingWorker = new SwingWorker<Object,Object>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        log.debug("doInBackground()");
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void done() {
                        log.debug("done");
                        //dialog.dispose();
                    }

                };

                swingWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        log.debug("event = {}", evt);
                        if( "state".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                            if( SwingWorker.StateValue.STARTED ==  evt.getNewValue() ) {
                                dialog.setVisible(true);
                                log.debug("after setVisible()");
                            }
                            else if( SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE == evt.getNewValue() ) {
                                dialog.dispose();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });


                swingWorker.execute();

            }
        });


    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're freezing your SwingWorker's PropertyChangeListener with that code. I would never set the dialog visible from within the PCL.

Rather, I'd do it here:

```
swingWorker.execute();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: @SuzanCioc: after starting the execution of the SwingWorker. See edit to answer.

Comment: This may not work if swing worker has time to finish execution before set visible is called. The dialog will be shown, but never hidden. But it should be hidden when worker finishes.